# Oracle: How to write a stored procedure that loops through dates to insert into a table

Tags: oracle, date, loops, stored-procedures

I would like to write a stored procedure that inserts some data into a table from another table (table b). But does one date from table b at a time. The date range is given as parameters in the stored procedures

Is my logic correct? I would really appreciate some tips

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE database_name.test(start_date,end_date)

-- declare parameters convert dates into numbers

BEGIN FOR i in start_date..end_date LOOP INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE SELECT
* FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE date = i END LOOP

END database_name.test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you need a loop?  I would think that you'd just want

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
  SELECT *
    FROM source_table
   WHERE source_table.date_column BETWEEN p_start_date AND p_end_date;
```

Comment: It is so I can update it when I please. And also it is a large table and the query is very slow. I can speed it up with indexes but I dont have DBA rights to

Comment: @shecode - Sorry, I'm not following.  Are you saying that there is a need for a loop?  If so, what would the loop do (or not do) that the `INSERT` statement would (or would not) do?

Comment: the loop would insert one date of aggregated data at a time

Comment: @shecode - But what does the loop accomplish that the single `INSERT` would not?  Why would you want to call a statement many different times in a loop when you can more efficiently run a single `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is not clear (from my point of view). If you need to create some dates list, you could use the following query to generate a list a dates between the begin date [bgin_d] and the end date [end_d]:

```
WITH dtes AS (SELECT SYSDATE bgin_d, SYSDATE + 30 end_d FROM DUAL)
    SELECT bgin_d + LEVEL
      FROM dtes
CONNECT BY bgin_d <= end_d;
```